# Weird blow fish icon on my taskbar tray

Tags: xubuntu, malware, taskbar

I have this weird icon on my taskbar tray. I worry that it is some malware or something. I cannot execute it or run it. I tried clicking it but it doesn't do anything.

[image: weird blowfish icon]

Comment: By the way, decent enough malware don't pop up conspicously in your system tray ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not malware, but [diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon), a clipboard manager, as you can confirm by killing it with `pkill -x diodon`. To uninstall it, issue `apt purge diodon`.